# face to white mark after folding the panel EXTJS

Tags: extjs, web-applications, extjs5

I have button on the first item of carousel on the Main View.
Button is managed by ButtonController and opens Form.
This form have tools: close, hide. When I click on close or hide tool on the forms after, for example closing I see white artifact. This looks like mark of header of Form..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqjz2.jpg)

Maybe this can be decided by trivial action?
Thanks

UPD: some code.

part of controller:

```
Ext.define('Foresto.view.main.ButtonController', {

extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

alias: 'controller.comenuform',
layout: 'vbox',

requires: [
           'Foresto.view.forms.1',
           'Foresto.view.forms.2',
           'Foresto.view.forms.3',
           'Foresto.view.forms.4'
           ],



views: ['Foresto.view.main.Main'],



cutForms: function () {
      Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
         
         layout: 'fit',
         renderTo: 'mainPart',
        
         autoshow: true,
         items: [{
            xtype: 'formsType4'
        }]
        
    })
    },
```

part of form:

```
Ext.define('Foresto.view.forms.Formf', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
title: 'testApp',
header: {
    cls: 'header-cls',
   
},

tools: [
        {type: 'minimize',
            handler: function(){
                this.up("panel").hide();
            }},
        {type: 'save'},
        {type:'close',
            handler: function(){
                this.up("panel").close();                                       
            }},
        ],

xtype: 'formsType4',

url: 'save-form.php',

defaults: {
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    labelWrap: true,
    afterLabelTextTpl: [
        '<span style="color:red;font-weight:normal" data-qtip="Required">*</span>'
    ]
},

items: [{...
```

and code of main:

```
Ext.define('Foresto.view.main.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
id:'control-panel',
xtype: 'app-main',
controller:'comenuform',

requires: [
    'Foresto.view.map.Map',
    
    'Foresto.view.main.ButtonController',
   
],

padding: 0,
id:"bighBox",
header: {
    cls: 'header-cls',
    title : {
        cls : 'header-title-cls',
        text : 'MyApp'
    }
},
tools: [{
    type: 'menu',
    handler: function(me) {
        var cp = me.down('panel');
        if (cp._hidden)
            cp.show(true);
        else
            cp.hide(true);
    }
}],

items:[{
    xtype: 'carousel',
    id: "mainPart",
    flex: 1,
    defaults: {
        border: true,
        ui: 'light'
    },
    items: [{
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'middle',
            pack: 'center'
        },
        
        cls: 'colorful2',
        defaults: {
            border: true,
            ui: 'light',
            flex: 1
        },
       
                items:[{
            
                    xtype:'button',
                    cls: 'button-cls',                  
                    text: 'buttonOfForm4',
                    id: "RenterId",
            
                    margin: 10,
                    width: 920,
                    height: 250,
                    length: 150,
                    handler: 'renterForms'
            ... (some other buttons, which call forms too)..
```

Comment: It will be good if you share some code? it's hard to track the issue without any code.

Comment: good recommendation. I did it